# Simplify 2 REGEX into 1

Tags: c#, regex

I have to detect a string that contains at least 1 uppercase letter different from the first one and don't contain lowercase letter. 
For example :

- `ABCD !` => acceptable case
- `Tommy Tom` => not acceptable case
- `Let something` => not acceptable case

Here what I did so far using 2 Regex :

```
!Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[a-z]") &&  Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[A-Z]");
```

I'm looking for a solution using a single REGEX.

Comment: Do you really need to use a regular expression? Using Linq is easier IMO

Comment: I think that using two regexes makes the code easier to understand, which is a good thing. Is there a reason to make it into one regex?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I totally agree for the elegance of code but I'm learning REGEX

Comment: I do not quite get your update. The examples still work with the original solutions.

Comment: Do you mean to say that `A1B` is valid and `A1A` is not? Try `^(?![^a-z]*[a-z])[^A-Z]*([A-Z])[^A-Z]*(?!\1)[A-Z]`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!%5b%5ea-z%5cn%5d*%5ba-z%5d%29%5b%5eA-Z%5cn%5d*%28%5bA-Z%5d%29%5b%5eA-Z%5cn%5d*%28%3f!%5c1%29%5bA-Z%5d&i=ABCD+!%0d%0aA1B%0d%0aA1A%0d%0aTommy+Tom%0d%0aLet+something&o=m).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's working I forgot a "!" when I copy the code. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?![^a-z]*[a-z])[^A-Z]*[A-Z]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F!%5B%5Ea-z%5D*%5Ba-z%5D%29%5B%5EA-Z%5D*%5BA-Z%5D&i=abc%0D%0AA123&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![^a-z]*[a-z])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a lowercase ASCII letter after any 0+ chars other than a lowercase ASCII letter
- `[^A-Z]*` - 0+ chars other than uppercase ASCII letters
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter.

Comment: I edit my question can you please update your answer.

Comment: @BenCottrell That is your opinion. I find my solution extremely easy to read, understand and extend.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You may do, but code is supposed to be human-readable for anyone who might look at it in the future.   RegEx is notoriously far less readable than plain code.  A lot of developers have a much harder time understanding a regex pattern than a simple boolean expression.

Comment: @BenCottrell The OP clarified in comments that this is a learning exercise and they understand that using two regexes would be better (for an appropriate metric of "better").

Comment: @BenCottrell You are posting some prejudiced stereotypes about regex, this is not helpful. I have been using regexes for 10+ years, and no one complained about anything. If the patterns are written effectively and do their job, there is nothing bad in using them.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I see, and that's a perfectly good reason.    Nonetheless, I'd still think that anyone using something like this in "real" code should go for the simplest and most readable solution rather than the one which is more expert-friendly and requires a lot more careful analysis to see what's happening

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, RegExes are fine if they're the simplest solution to a problem, it's all relative though;   Developers are more likely to be familiar with boolean expressions than RegEx.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor, it's work also ! When I copied the line of code I forgot to delete the first "!".

Answer (score 1):

An option is

```
^[^a-zA-Z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*$
```

Repeat zero or more non-alphabetical characters, match an uppercase character, and then repeat zero or more non-lowercase characters again until the end of the string is reached.

https://regex101.com/r/6JZCDr/2

The `A-Z` in the first character set isn't necessary, but it will result in fewer steps, because then the second character set's `[A-Z]` will match without any backtracking (if the match is possible).

Comment: Thank you ! I edit my question can you please update your answer.

Comment: The regex still works, but I updated the regex101 link with your text if that's what you were looking for

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance, it's work ! When I copied the line of code I forgot to delete the first "!".

Comment: I find this regex very intuitive, simple and robust

Answer (score 0):

Consider a regex supporting multilingual input ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3D%5CP%7BLl%7D*%24%29%20%20%23%20Lowercase%20letters%20are%20not%20allowed%0D%0A%5CP%7BLu%7D*%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Allow%20offset%20for%20the%201st%20uppercase%20letter%0D%0A%28%5Cp%7BLu%7D%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Capture%20the%201st%20uppercase%20letter%0D%0A.*%3F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Allow%20offset%20for%20the%202nd%20uppercase%20letter%0D%0A%5Cp%7BLu%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Require%20the%202nd%20uppercase%20letter%0D%0A%28%3F%3C!%5C1%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20..different%20from%20the%201st%20uppercase%20letter&i=ABCD%20!%0D%0ATommy%20Tom%0D%0ALet%20something%0D%0A%0D%0A%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%0D%0A%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%99%0D%0A%CE%95%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC%0D%0A%CE%95%CE%9B%CE%9B%CE%97%CE%9D%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%91%0D%0A%0D%0A1AA%0D%0A1AB%0D%0AA1A%0D%0AA1B%0D%0AAA1%0D%0AAB1%0D%0A%0D%0A1AAA2%0D%0A1AA2A%0D%0A1AAB2%0D%0A1AA2B&o=xm)):

```
^(?=\P{Ll}*$)\P{Lu}*(\p{Lu}).*?\p{Lu}(?<!\1)
```

Explained:

```
^(?=\P{Ll}*$)  # Lowercase letters are not allowed
\P{Lu}*        # Allow offset for the 1st uppercase letter
(\p{Lu})       # Capture the 1st uppercase letter
.*?            # Allow offset for the 2nd uppercase letter
\p{Lu}         # Require the 2nd uppercase letter
(?<!\1)        # ..different from the 1st uppercase letter
```

Where:

- `\P{Ll}` means "not a lowercase letter"
- `\P{Lu}` means "not an uppercase letter"
- `\p{Lu}` means "an uppercase letter"

*(pay attention to `\P` and `\p` register)*